# Why is there no std::find_not in the STL?

Tags: c++

I'm just wondering why there is no std::find_not (taking a value and not a lambda - which is different from std::find_if_not) in the STL. [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Misc.html#the_boost_algorithm_library.Misc.misc_inner_algorithms.find_not) has it for the exact reason I think it should exist:

> The existing find variants are: find(), find_if(), and find_if_not(). It seems natural to also have find_not(), for the very reason that we have find_if_not() -- to avoid having to write a lambda to wrap the negation of the find condition.

Is it just a matter of 'nobody proposed it yet' or is there something else?

- mike

Comment: `std::find` is used to find an element based on equality. Are you suggesting `std::find_not` would use `!=` instead of `==`? Or do you mean closer to `std::find_if_not` which would indeed just be the per-element negation of `std::find_if`, which does already exist.

Comment: Probably was considered and rejected as an unlikely edge case, and in that unlikely situation that could easily be accomplished with the obvious lambda .  But that's just speculation.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the proposal for `find_if_not`:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2569.pdf

It includes this justification:

> Just as copy_if is the inverse of remove_copy_if, find_if_not is the inverse of find_if:
> it returns an iterator pointing to the first element that fails to satisfy a predicate p. It's
> worth adding for the same reason.

`copy_if` is proposed in the same document. It includes this:

> It is formally redundant [...], but it's worth adding anyways. First, C++ isn't really a
> functional language and transforming a predicate into its negation is sometimes awkward.
> Second, the workaround of using double negatives is not unconfusing

So my best guess without asking the author is "both `copy_if` and `find_if_not` were added as a convenience to make negative *predicates* easier. Since `find` is value-based and the author appears at least a bit reluctant to add redundant versions of algorithms, `find_not` wasn't considered."

Comment: _using double negatives is not unconfusing_ mumble mumble...